# INSERTING into custom mysql database table

Tags: mysql, node.js, ajax

I am currently trying to insert data into a specific table name that is saved to a variable but I keep on receiving a ER_PARSE_ERROR whenever I try executing it.

```
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Test' SET `date` = '201
9-05-07', `league` = '1', `matchup` = '1'' at line 1
```

Here my what the post request looks like

```
app.post('/addData', function(req, res) {
  var id = req.body.id
  var data = {
    date: req.body.date,
    league: req.body.league,
    matchup: req.body.matchup,
  }
  con.query('INSERT INTO ? SET ?', [id, data], function(err, resp) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.redirect('back');
  });
});
```

It seems like from the error message, there are additional quotes around Test when passed into the query but when doing console.log(id), it just prints out Test without the quotes.

Comment: Aren't all database tables 'custom'?

Answer (score 0):

```js
app.post('/addData', function (req, res) {

    var data = {
        id: req.body.id,
        date: req.body.date,
        league: req.body.league,
        matchup: req.body.matchup,
    };
    con.query('INSERT INTO Test SET ?', data, function (err, resp) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.redirect('back');
    });
});
```

Can you try this?

Comment: Forgot to mention this but, the table is based on what the user chooses. So I have a form that contains input boxes and a select box (with name="id") that basically lists all the tables in the database. So if Test2 was selected, then the query would be INSERT INTO Test2 instead of INSERT INTO Test

Answer (score 0):

```js
// This is the best ES6 way you can try out make some changes in your date format.
app.post('/addData', async (req, res) => {

    var data = {
        id: req.body.id,
        date: req.body.date,
        league: req.body.league,
        matchup: req.body.matchup,
    };
    await con.query('INSERT INTO Test SET ?', data, (err, resp) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.redirect('back');
    });
});
```

Comment: Forgot to mention this but, the table is based on what the user chooses. So I have a form that contains input boxes and a select box (with name="id") that basically lists all the tables in the database. So if Test2 was selected, then the query would be INSERT INTO Test2 instead of INSERT INTO Test